# Браузер не видит изменения локального времени на компьютере

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, internet-explorer, webbrowser

Столкнулся с проблемой быстрого определения в **Google Chrome**, **Internet Explorer**, что пользователь перевел часы на компьютере в **Windows**.
Порядок воспроизведения:

- Изменить время в системных часах на несколько минут вперед или назад.
- Выполнить в консоли браузера `new Date()`
- **В течение 1 - 2 минут** в консоли выводится старая метка времени.

Ошибка возникает только в Windows. На Linux браузер оперативно определяет, что время в локальных часах изменилось.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Интересно. Если при этот открыть новое окно, то в нем new Date() будет сразу выдавать измененное время, а в открытом ранее то же new Date() будет по-прежнему выдавать старое время.

Comment: А, вот, кажется, как раз про это: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43293

Comment: Да, похоже на эту ошибку. В issue описана проблема с timezone, но возможно связано. Но как я понял, баг так и не исправили.